# Hopefully simple Python curiosity

Tags: python-2.6

i am new to python and learning it for my job functions. im following a very basic beginners tutorial and most of it looks very familiar and similar to other languages ive used. but... when i do the very simple

```
print('hello world')
```

i get the expected response of

```
hello world
```

but when i do another simple task:

```
x = 5
print('x is', x)
```

i get:

```
('x is', 5)
```

the print command is preserving the parentheses and single quotes and for the life of me i cant figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Python 2.6, `print` is a statement and not a function. As a result, the arguments are not expected to be in parentheses (note that this has changed in version 3.0).

This code will do what you intended:

```
print 'x is', x
```

Your original code actually creates a tuple and prints it.

Comment: ok thank you, so its just the version of python im using, that answer works fine for me. i will adjust my syntax accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The use of print statement is echoing the type to string. `('x', 1)` is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Python evaluates ('x is', 5) and then turns the results (a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple)) into a string, which is ('x is', 5).  Leave out the parentheses to get what you want:

```
print 'x is', 5
```

See the [Python print documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) for more.